# Rails, datatabse creation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to create database using default user 'postgres'
but while executing `rails db:create` not seleting role name postgres, it's selecting my systme name 'mysystem'.

below is my database.yml file code

```
default: &default
 adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
 # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
 # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
 pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

 development:
  <<: *default
  database: user_development
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>

 test:
  <<: *default
  database: user_test

 production:
  <<: *default
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_HOST_URL'] %>
  database: user_production
  username: <%= ENV['USER_DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['USER_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Error while executing `rails db:create`

```
 rails aborted!
  ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: FATAL:  role "mysystem" does not exist      

 Caused by:
  PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  role "mysystem" does not exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some helpful information here:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.7/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
sections 3.12 and 3.13

I think your issue might be the host: setting. This should either
be /tmp for a unix domain socket, or an ip address / hostname, if used.

Settings I used in testing:
postgresql 12.3 debian unix.

```
Using this pg_hba.conf:
local   all             all                                     ident
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             192.168.50.0/24         md5
```

You might want a hostssl entry for data being sent between machines.

```
# using the same "user" database name you have. 
rails new user -d postgresql

#setting the password for testing.
psql
alter role user1 password 'testpass';

cd user/config
emacs database.yml

#example using ident authentication - being logged in as the same unix user.
production:
  <<: *default
  host: /tmp
  database: user_production
  username: user1
  password: nil

# using a host ip address
production:
  <<: *default
  host: 192.168.50.6
  database: user_production
  username: user1
  password: testpass

# using a host ip address with env vars
#export USER_DATABASE_USERNAME="user1"
#export USER_DATABASE_PASSWORD="testpass"
production:
  <<: *default
  host: 192.168.50.6
  database: user_production
  username: <%= ENV['USER_DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['USER_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>

# hardcoding everything in the url for illustration:
production:
  <<: *default
  url: postgres://user1:testpass@192.168.50.6/user_production

# best practice according to doc. DATABASE_URL has precedence over database.yaml when set
# we are just indicating we know that here.
# export DATABASE_URL="postgres://user1:testpass@192.168.50.6/user_production"
production:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>

user1@debian10 /home/user1/rails/user > RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails db:create
Created database 'user_production'

user1@debian10 /home/user1/rails/user > RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails db:drop
Dropped database 'user_production'

#Seeing what is being used:
RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails runner 'p ActiveRecord::Base.configurations'

#<ActiveRecord::DatabaseConfigurations:0x0000564e40093fa0 @configurations=[#<ActiveRecord::DatabaseConfigurations::HashConfig:0x0000564e40092f60 @env_name="default", @name="primary", @configuration_hash={:adapter=>"postgresql", :encoding=>"unicode", :pool=>5}>, #<ActiveRecord::DatabaseConfigurations::HashConfig:0x0000564e400928f8 @env_name="development", @name="primary", @configuration_hash={:adapter=>"postgresql", :encoding=>"unicode", :pool=>5, :database=>"user_development"}>, #<ActiveRecord::DatabaseConfigurations::HashConfig:0x0000564e400921a0 @env_name="test", @name="primary", @configuration_hash={:adapter=>"postgresql", :encoding=>"unicode", :pool=>5, :database=>"user_test"}>, #<ActiveRecord::DatabaseConfigurations::UrlConfig:0x0000564e40091b60 @env_name="production", @name="primary", @configuration_hash={:adapter=>"postgresql", :encoding=>"unicode", :pool=>5, :username=>"user1", :password=>"testpass", :database=>"user_production", :host=>"192.168.50.6"}, @url="postgres://user1:testpass@192.168.50.6/user_production">]>
```